# In Angularjs how do you alter a mock service per test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-services

**Code example**

This is probably better explained in code, so I have included a detailed, abstracted example below - where my question is repeated in the comments.

**Example Summary**

For example, you mock out a reasonably complex mock service, and in the first test you want the mock service to give a positive result for one function (by return code 200 in the example below). In the second test, you want the same function to return a negative result, say 500.

I found that I can simply inject the provider and overwrite the method, but is that the correct way? See "test 2" below.

```
describe('CommentArea', function() {

  var controller
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app', function($provide) {
      // Base mock definition
      $provide.provider('comments', function() {
        this.$get = function() {
          return {
            create: function() {
              return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                resolve({ code: 200 })
              })
            },
            delete: function() {
              return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                resolve({ code: 200 })
              })
            }
          }
        }
      })
    })

    inject(function($componentController) {
      controller = $componentController('CommentArea')
    })
  })

  // Start tests
  //
  // Test 1 - Use the above mocked service "as is" - happy path scenario
  //
  it('appends comment when successful', function() {
    expect(controller.commentCount).toEqual(0)
    controller.create() // uses the comments service create method
    expect(controller.commentCount).toEqual(1)    
  })

  // Test 2 - Use the above mocked service with a slight modification
  // This time the create function will fail
  //
  it('does not append comment when unsuccessful', inject(function(comments) {
    // overwrite for failure condition here
    // QUESTION - is this acceptable? It seems odd just overwriting it
    // so directly
    comments.create = function () {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve({ code: 500 })
      })
    }

    expect(controller.commentCount).toEqual(0)
    controller.create() // uses the comments service create method
    expect(controller.commentCount).toEqual(0)    
  }))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this means that mocked return values shouldn't be defined in `beforeEach`.

One of the ways is to make functions return local variables that are defined in common function scope (`describe` block):

```
var createValue;
...
beforeEach(module('app', { comments: {
  create: function () { return createValue }, ...
}))
...
createValue = Promise.resolve(200);
comments.create();
```

Local variables have a downside. If `createValue` wasn't redefined by mistake in next test, tests may become cross-contaminated.

Moreover, this kind of mocks doesn't solve an important task; mocked functions aren't spied.

This is exactly the task that Jasmine spies are supposed to solve:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  module('app', { comments: jasmine.createSpyObj('comments', ['create', 'delete']) });
});
```

`module` should be wrapped with a function in this case because a new spy object is supposed to be created on each `beforeEach` call.

Then return values are defined in-place:

```
comment.create.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(200))
comments.create();
```

Comment: This is great - just tried it and it works. I don't *fully* understand it - so I will need to go away to go over it a few times to let it settle in my brain. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - can you clarify "should be wrapped with a function" ?

Comment: Notice that in first example it is `beforeEach(module(..))`, and in second it's `beforeEach(function () { module(...) })`. Both work for `module`, but the latter allows to renew `jasmine.createSpyObj(...)` on every spec, which is the desirable behaviour.